# timerfd mysteriously set int to 0 when read()

Tags: unix, timer

I am doing an timerfd hello world in ubuntu 14.04, but got a strange situation: the int count is reset after read timerfd but uint64_int not.

```
int main(int agrc, char **argv) {
    unsigned int heartbeat_interval = 1;
    struct itimerspec next_timer;
    struct timespec now;

    if (clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &now) == -1)
        err_sys((WHERE + std::string("timer error")).c_str());
    next_timer.it_value.tv_sec = now.tv_sec;
    next_timer.it_value.tv_nsec = 0;
    next_timer.it_interval.tv_sec = heartbeat_interval;
    next_timer.it_interval.tv_nsec = 0;
    int timefd = timerfd_create(CLOCK_REALTIME, 0);
    if (timerfd_settime(timefd, TFD_TIMER_ABSTIME, &next_timer, NULL) == -1) {
        err_sys((WHERE).c_str());
    }
    uint64_t s;
    int exp;
    int count = 1;
    uint64_t count1=0;
    while (1) {
        s = read(timefd, &exp, sizeof(uint64_t));
        if (s != sizeof(uint64_t)) {
            err_sys((WHERE).c_str());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int exp;
^^^

s = read(timefd, &exp, sizeof(uint64_t));
                  ^^^         ^^^^^^^^
```

Unless your `int` and `uint64_t` types are the same size, this is a very bad idea. What's most likely happening is that the 64 bits you're reading are overwriting `exp` *and* whatever else happens to be next to it on the stack.

Actually, even if they *are* the same size, it's a bad idea. What you *should* have is something like:

```
s = read(timefd, &exp, sizeof(exp));
```

That way, you're guaranteed to never overwrite the data and your next line would catch the problem for you:

```
if (s != sizeof(uint64_t)) {
```

It won't solve the problem that an unsigned integral type and an integral type will be treated differently but you can fix that just by using the right type for `exp`.